# Расположение ключей и значений Request.Params

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Есть в проекте вот такая вот строчка.

```
String arg = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

И я хочу узнать откуда она тянет данные. Нашёл в коде

```
__doPostBack
```

Но хоть убей не могу понять где хранятся сами ключи и закладываемые в них параметры. Полностью прочесал и aspx и cs файлы. Может кто нибудь подсказать где можно найти ключи с передаваемыми в них значениями? Мне нужно изменить значение передаваемое в `__EVENTARGUMENT`. Где в проектах они обычно хранятся?

Comment: Request.Params содержит список параметров Post и Get запросов, которые приходят на веб-сервер от клиента.

Comment: @AndreiS. а если чуть попроще, где мне сейчас искать значения и параметры? Где это в проекте храниться?

Comment: нигде, они определяются, когда поступает запрос на какой-либо роут

Comment: @Arthur как понять ни где? Где то же они формируются и откуда то передаются, и мне нужно поменять передаваемое значение.

Comment: это скрыто под капотом фреймворка, из проекта они не конфигурируются. ну можете посмотреть всякие json файлы в проекте, но не думаю, что вы там что-либо найдёте

Comment: @Андрей Смотрите, вы отправляете запрос на свой сайт http:\\localhost:80\Main.aspx?some_parameter=111 Затем на сервере вы вызываете код var getValue =  Request.Params["some_parameter"']; и getValue имеет значение 111. Тоже самое происходит и с POST запросами. В вашем случае это POST

Comment: @Arthur ну как то же это задавалось какие именно значения будут передаваться по конкретным ключам. Значит и изменить можно.

Comment: Попробуйте открыть разметку сформированной страницы в браузере и поискать __EVENTARGUMENT там

Comment: @AndreiS. отлично. Это я понял. Где это найти? Где я могу передать передаваемое значение?

Comment: @AndreiS. уже пробовал.

Comment: @AndreiS. я вас сначала не правильно понял. Попробовал и вот что откопал `<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
`

Comment: @AndreiS. только что теперь дальше?

Comment: @Андрей зависит от того, что вы хотите :) потому что, вопрос был, откуда берутся ключи в массиве Request.Params

Comment: @AndreiS. поменять значение eventArgument. Показывает что этот код в моём aspx. Но реально его там нет.

Comment: @AndreiS. мне нужно поменять значение ассоциируемое с этим ключом.

Comment: @Андрей Вы можете сделать это на стороне клиента через JS, вызвав функцию __doPostBack("eventTarget", "myEventArgument") и передав ей нужные вам значения как параметры

Comment: @AndreiS. всё разобрался уже как это делается, спасибо за помощь.